# White label solution for ecards

Tags: open-source, software-development, email, flashcard

I am looking in for white label software for ecards for our site. Should support mobile and tablet. Any recommendations is welcome. I can see few website provide ecards as a service. Any recommendation on that will be useful. Thanks

Operating system: It should be Windows.
Technology: Ideally .Net & C# but would also consider other languages
Budget: Yes would be willing to pay for the software

Requirements: 
1. Display a list of ecards under different categories
2. Personalize the card with custom message, name, add photo 
3. Cards design should be in HTML 5 so that can be viewed from mobile as well
4. Cards should have static and dynamic version so that if browser doesn't support HTML 5 it should fall back to static design
5. Add multiple recipients/ upload recipients through a excel template
6. Delivery/ read notification

An admin site along with that for adding and removing ecards will be nice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially list your requirements as exact as possible, including the platform it should run on. For integration with "your site" it might be helpful to know with what it should be integrated.